Sonatype Nexus Docker Registry - Disc Consumption
I recently switched to using the Sonatype Nexus Repository for hosting my Docker images. Previously, I used the Docker registry image to store my Docker images.
With approximately 30 Docker images, the Docker registry image consumed around 13GB of space. However, after switching to the Sonatype Nexus image, the storage usage has increased to about 22GB which is huge.
I'm unable to pinpoint the cause of this significant increase in storage consumption. Any assistance in identifying and resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
with this data, I am creating the repo...
'{
  "name": "'$docker_hosted_repository_name'",
  "online": true,
  "storage": {
    "blobStoreName": "default",
    "strictContentTypeValidation": true,
    "writePolicy": "allow"
  },
  "component": {
    "proprietaryComponents": true
  },
  "docker": {
    "v1Enabled": false,
    "forceBasicAuth": true,
    "httpPort": '$docker_port'
   }
}'

Thanks in advance.
